# Little Timmy and the Lunchbox

Tags: wordplay

What 11 letters and numbers did Timmy say today at school when he opened up his lunchbox?

Hint #1

> What he said was a complete sentence.

Hint #2

> Only one of them is used twice all others are used only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be too broad - it's basically "guess which combination of letter and number names that sound like words I combined together to make something resembling a relevant sentence."

11 numbers and letters, exactly one repeat:

> Y I C P B N J N H 2 O
>  Why, I see PB&J and H₂O!

Other possible variants might include ...

11, no repeats:

> Y I C U R A P B N J 2
>  Why, I see you are a PB&J too!

13, letters only, no repeats:

> O G I C U R A Q T P B N J
>  Oh, gee, I see you are a cutie PB&J!

Of course nothing in the question restricts *what* he says, so I expect other people will be able to come up with any number of alternatives.  You might consider refining the question to confine valid answers to the one you intend.

Answer (score 0):

> He was surprised to find PB&J sandwiches again, so he exclaimed:
>
>  3 DAYS IN A ROW !!?